# Cant find error in my Code? C

Tags: c

The idea is to be able to add a name to the end of the linked list when the user enters "1" and print and delete the first name in the linked list when the user enters "0". This is working if there is only 2 names in the linked list but anymore than 2 it only does the first name and last name, yet I cannot see my error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define bool int
#define TRUE 1d
#define FALSE 0

typedef struct node{
     char name[100];
     struct node *next;
} Node;

Node *head;

void call(){
    if(head == NULL){
            printf("List is empty.\n");
        }
        else{
            Node *temp;
            printf("Calling %s\n", head->name);
            if(head->next!=NULL){
                temp = head->next;
                free(head);
                head = temp;
            }
            else{
                head = NULL;
            }
        }
}

void add(char input[]){
        Node *temp;
        temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        strcpy(temp->name, input);
        temp->next = NULL;
        if(head == NULL){
            head = temp;
        }
        else{
            head->next = temp;
        }
}

int main(){

    start:;
    int user_menu_answer;
    char waste;

    printf("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n");
    printf("0) Call a customer\n");
    printf("1) Add a customer\n");
    printf("2) Quit\n");
    printf("Please input your command \n");
    printf("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n");
    scanf("%d%c", &user_menu_answer, &waste);

    //main menu options
    if(user_menu_answer == 0){
        call();
        goto start;
    }
    else if (user_menu_answer == 1){
        char input[23];
        printf("Please give me the customers name: \n");
        scanf("%[^\n]", input);
        add(input);
        goto start;
    }
    else if (user_menu_answer == 2){
        printf("Quitting...");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        printf("You did not enter a valid option, Please try again. \n");
        goto start;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*The idea is to be able to add a name to the end of the linked list...*" - where is the variable that keeps track of the end of the linked list?

Comment: If you set `temp->next` to null and then add it after head you've just lost the rest of the list.

Comment: i think the problem is same head variable is used for head and tail both. so adding name adds node at head->next which should be tail->next

Comment: Don't `#define bool` and the constants yourself! C has a boolean type, use it! See `stdbool.h`.

Comment: You may want to look at the [**insert_node**](https://pastebin.com/BirWtkvb) function contained within that circular linked list example (in a circular list `last->next` points to `head` allowing traversal of the list from any node to any node without starting at `head` each time, otherwise all list operations are generic to a linked-list)

Answer (score 0):

First MISTAKE:

```
void call(){

if(head == NULL){
        printf("List is empty.\n");
    }
    else{
        Node *temp;
        printf("Calling %s\n", head->name);
        if(head->next!=NULL){
            temp = head->next;
            free(head);
            head = temp;
        }
        else{
           free(head); //you don't free the memory if it's just one in the list
            head = NULL;
        }
    }
 }
```

Second mistake:

```
void add(char input[]){
    Node *AuxHead; //create an aux to the head so you can move threw the list
    Node *temp;
    temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
if(temp!=NULL) //verify if it got allocated
{
    strcpy(temp->name, input);
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(head == NULL){
        head = temp;
    }
    else{
       AuxHead=head; //pass the address of the head
       while(AuxHead->next!=NULL) //catch the lest node of the list
          AuxHead=AuxHead->next;
        AuxHead->next = temp; //make the temp, the last of the list
    }
}
}
```

Comment: God bless you sir!